# Tabindex in grouped radio button

Tags: html, radio-button, tabindex

i need to put tabindex on grouped radio buttons so that the tabbing focuses each radio button sequentially. For this, I need to use only "the tab key" (not the arrow keys) and also, i have to keep them(radio buttons) in a single group.

```
<input onclick="javascript:showUserName();" name="userSearch" value="UN" type="radio">
<input onclick="javascript:showLoginID();" name="userSearch" value="UL" type="radio">
<input onclick="javascript:showEmployeeID();" name="userSearch" value="EI" type="radio">
```

The problem is that tabindex only focuses the selected radio button in a group and on the subsequent tab it goes to next set of Html element, but not the next radio button in group. I know, this is standard browser behaviour, but is there any way i can do some work around so that my requirements are met?

Will writing  a JS code to monitor onkeypress event on my page to monitor for tab and the radio group combination to explicitly focus on the radio group buttons a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind onkeydown to your input and check if the keycode matches tab press keycode and then implement your own behaviour.

Something like:

```
<input onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==%TABKEYCODE%) handleTabPress(); return false;".... />
```

in handleTabPress you can then implement your own mechanic on what should happen if one presses the tab key. And you should set the focus onto the radio button in onclick event.

Comment: THnaks i implemented the functionality, it served my purpose.